# Second dynamic ip to my azure vm using the portal

Tags: azure, dynamic, ip, centos7

Adding a second dynamic ip to the vm but it didn't work..

This seemed pretty straight forward and shows in the portal Network Interface:

Azure Portal

[image: Portal]

but nothing in the VM itself.

VM Machine

[image: VM Machine]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`ifconfig` will only show you the first IP. The rest of your IPs you need to add manually.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell#linux-redhat-centos-and-others) for how to do it.